# Returning a class type based on int value

Tags: c#, generics

Right now, I have an enum like this:

```
public enum ReferenceType
{
    Language = 1,
    Period = 2,
    Genre = 3
}
```

Language, Period, and Genre are all entity classes that map back to tables in my database. I also have model classes that map almost 1 to 1 with the entity classes, which I then display in a view.

I also have a service method like this:

```
List<Model> Get<Model, Entity>()
        where Model : BaseModel
        where Entity : BaseEntity;
```

I can call it like `Service.Get<LanguageModel, Language>()` and it will return every row from table Language from my database and automatically convert them into LanguageModels, which I'll then display in my view.

I want to create a wrapper method around the `Get()` method where you simply need to pass in an integer and it will call my `Get()` method filling in the entity and model class types automatically. The only problem is I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the actual implementation behind this.

The pseudo-code would be along the lines of:

1. Call `WrapperGet((int)ReferenceType.Genre)`
2. Wrapper method resolves the entity type (`Genre`) and model type (`GenreModel`)
3. Call the `Get()` method with the resolved entity and model types, so it'd be `Get<GenreModel, Genre>()`
4. Return the results

How would I actually go implementing this in C#?

Comment: So essentially you want a generic repository... what ORM are you using, is it Entity Framework?

Comment: Yeah. We're using EF 4.0

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, this looks like a good use case for AutoMapper, which is a rules-based engine for converting one class to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want strongly-typed results, you'll have to forgo the idea of passing an `int` or enum in, and switch to calling `Get` directly or making methods like this:

```
List<LanguageModel> GetLanguages() { return Get<LanguageModel, Language>(); }
```

If weakly typed works for you, then I'd go with Saeed's solution, but the types need a little changing to work.  `Model` was a generic type in your example, so presumably he meant `List<BaseModel>` as the return type.  But a `List<LanguageModel>` isn't a `List<BaseModel>`!  You can resolve this by either making it return `IEnumerable<BaseModel>` or changing `Get` to return a `List<BaseModel>`, or change it afterwards with `return new List<BaseModel>(Get<...`

Answer (score 2):

I can't think for a full generic way, I think simplest way is as below:

```
List<Model> WrapperGet(int type)
{
   switch (type)
   {
      case 1: return Get<LanguageModel, Language>();
      ....
   }
   return null;
}
```